# Why am I getting gibberish when outputting to a text file from powershell?

Tags: powershell, output

I am trying to output all the file names in a directory to a file.  Seems simple, but in the future I will be creating useful information based off the file names and outputting to a file for another system.

When I output the information to a file it shows as gibberish when I open in notepad.  Outputting to the screen looks fine.

Here is my code:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "s:\centmobile\rates\currentrates\forupload\"
$outfile = "s:\centmobile\rates\currentrates\test.txt" 
"New File"|Out-File $outfile -Encoding ascii

foreach ($f in $files){
Get-Content $f.FullName  | Add-Content $outfile -Encoding Ascii
Write-Output $f.FullName
}
```

Screen output looks good:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> S:\CentMobile\Software\Dev\cre8hdrinfo.ps1
S:\centmobile\rates\currentrates\forupload\2019406BICS_BC_Rates_ForUpload.xlsx
S:\centmobile\rates\currentrates\forupload\2019406BICS_FC_Rates_ForUpload.xlsx
```

File output looks not so good..

```
New File
PK     ! –~íGq  %   [Content_Types].xml ¢(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ¬”ËNÃ0E÷HüCä-JÜ²@5í‚Ç
A%Ê˜xÒXqlËã–öï™¸U(4BÍ&–ã™{O&3žÌ6NÖàQY“³q6b  ˜ÂJe–9û\¼¤÷,Á ŒÚÈÙÍ¦×W“ÅÖ&”m0gUîs,*hfÖ¡“ÒúFÚú%w¢¨ÅøíhtÇk˜†VƒM'OPŠ•Éó†^ïH<hdÉã.°õÊ™pN«B"åk#¹¤{‡Œ2cVÊá
a0ÞéÐžüm°Ï{§Òx%!™ÞDC|£ù·õõ—µuv^¤ƒÒ–¥*@ÚbÕP2t„Ä
 4:‹kÖeÜgüc0ò¸Œi¿/
÷p ý0o„~U¦F~ºšèT»*PÏË)¢L!†­º¢hŸs%<Èài\8Õ>ÇAÍ<÷Ö!µ‡ÿWá0·mvêH|PpœÜ®   8:Ò•pqÙÛÎ2d‡7—Üô  ÿÿ PK     ! µU0#ô   L   _rels/.rels ¢(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ¬’MOÃ0†ïHü‡È÷ÕÝBKwAH»!T~€IÜµ£$Ý¿'TƒG½~üÊÛÝ<êÈ!öâ4¬‹;#¶w­†—úqu*&r–Fq¬áÄvÕõÕö™GJy(v½*«¸¨¡KÉß#FÓñD±Ï.W   ¥†=™ZÆMYÞbø®ÕBSí­†°·7 ê“Ï›×–¦é
?ˆ9LìÒ™ÈsbgÙ®|Èl!õùUSh9i°bžr:"y_dlÀóD›¿ý|-NœÈR"4ø2ÏGÇ% õZ´4ñËyÄ7    Ã«ÈðÉ‚‹¨Þ  ÿÿ PK     ! …ë —  †     xl/workbook.xml¬Umo›:þ~¥ýÆýLÁ¼ƒ’LI ÝJÛT¥]÷¥Òä€S¬æÓ¤ªößwlBš.ÕÔu‹ˆß?çœç&vu¥ÝÞQÖLutféirVÐævª¹ÊŒP×:›W¬!Sýtú‡Ù»&[ÆïÖŒÝi ÐtS½¢M³ËKRãîŒµ¤•
ã50ä·f×r‚‹®$DÔ•i[–oÖ˜6ú€ó×`°Í†æ$ay_“F œTX ý®¤m7¢ÕùkàjÌïúÖÈYÝÄšVT<(P]«óøü¶a¯+0{‡<mÇáñá,hìñ&X:¹ª¦9gÛˆ3€6Ò'ö#ËDè™v§>x’krrOe¬¸ÿFVþËCÖ£!–ÒJÎ{#šwàfë³É†Väz®†Ûö3®e¤*]«p'Ò‚
RLõ †lKžMð¾]ô´‚U¹¶§›³ƒœ/¸V
...
```

Comment: Pardon me if this is a silly question, but are you sure that all the files in folder `s:\centmobile\rates\currentrates\forupload` are ASCII encoded?

Comment: The 1st file obviously was a .zip file `Most of the signatures end with the short integer 0x4b50, which is stored in little-endian ordering. Viewed as an ASCII string this reads "PK", the initials of the inventor Phil Katz. Thus, when a ZIP file is viewed in a text editor the first two bytes of the file are usually "PK"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your screen output and file looks very different is that you're not outputting the same content at all to screen and file.

With:

```
Get-Content $f.FullName  | Add-Content $outfile -Encoding Ascii
```

you are, as the command implies, getting the *content* of every file and outputting to $outfile.

While with:

```
>Write-Output $f.FullName
```

You are just outputting the list of file names to screen.

As your question says it's the filenames you're after, just change:

```
Get-Content $f.FullName  | Add-Content $outfile -Encoding Ascii
```

to:

```
$f.FullName  | Add-Content $outfile -Encoding Ascii
```

and it should output the same thing to screen as to the file.

A good way to check/troubleshoot here would've been to just remove everything after:

```
Get-Content $f.FullName
```

and look at the output, which will look very similar to the file and give you a hint that something's wrong there.

Comment: @queue In general, filenames on the systems that PowerShell runs on are not fully supported by the ASCII character set. Use a Unicode encoding such as UTF-8 and pass that metadata along to readers of the file.

Answer (score 0):

[`Get-Content` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6#outputs) returns strings or bytes (*strings* in your case). The gibberish you are getting comes from interpretation *binary* values from `xlsx` files as `Ascii` strings (**unsolvable** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case).

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

From [fileformatcommons.com](http://www.fileformatcommons.com/xlsx-file-format/):

> xlsx files are actually **zip** files in disguise…
>   xlsx file character encoding / charset is **binary**

From [.ZIP File Format Specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

> local file header signature (4 bytes)  `0x04034b50`

From [Zip (file format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Structure) at Wikipedia:

> Most of the signatures end with the short integer `0x4b50`, which is
>   stored in little-endian ordering. Viewed as an ASCII string this reads
>   "PK", the initials of the inventor Phil Katz. Thus, when a ZIP file is
>   viewed in a text editor the first two bytes of the file are usually
>   "PK".